# piecewise linear interpolation in R

Tags: r, linear-interpolation, piecewise

I understand you can use approx function to linearly interpolate.
However, I could not find anywhere how to piecewise linearly interpolate the pair of points.
For instance, assume x<-c(1,4,3,2)   y<-c(4,3,2,1)

Can anybody give me an answer? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Let me make it clear for you. When I mean "pair of points", it means (1,4)

Comment: Let me make it clear for you. When I mean "pair of points", 
it means that there are 4 points. they are respectively, p1= (1,4), p2(4,3), p(3,2), P(2,1)
What I would like to do is to connect P1 and P2, and P2 and P3, and P3 and P4 in piecewise linearly interpolated(say, 50 points)
such that the interpolated points should make a path from P1=>P2=>P3=>P4 in sequence.
So, the expected shape when you plot should look somewhat like ">" instead of "V" shape, as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what "pair of points" you are referring to.  But you can use the `approx()` function on the pair of vectors you provide.

```
x <- c(1, 4, 3, 2) 
y <- c(4, 3, 2, 1)
interp <- approx(x, y)
plot(x, y, pch=16, cex=2)
points(interp, col="red")
```